# How to deploy Deep Learning models on AWS Lambda where models weights are more than 400 MB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an app working in `FastAPI` already. To cut the costs, I'm trying to shift everything to `Lambda`. The problem is that when I `zip` code + dependencies + model weights, it becomes a `700MB` file and `Lambda` accepts `50 MB`. I tried uploading it to `S3` also but while adding the link to `Lambda` runtime, it throws an error as:

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

There's a way around that I copy and paste model's weight using `boto3` just when the script runs but it'll mean that with every initiation, my model weights will be copied, with each call until the code is running. Copying and loading the `400 MB` model will be a slow process.

Since there's no support for `Docker` directly on `Lambda Runtime`, I found out that you can use [`mangum` with `Docker`](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-fastapi-and-aws-lambda-container-3e524c586f01). If I use docker, it'll install dependencied + copy model weights from the URL everytime the function is called.

What would be a good way for this process?

Comment: Lambda supports [up to 10GB ephemeral storage](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/) but you'd be repeatedly downloading large files from, probably, S3 into Lambda temp space. Probably better to look at network-attached EFS or burned into container image, if the data doesn't change frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options are there

1. Using Amazon Elastic File System (EFS) - EFS is to mount a file system directly to the Lambda function, and the files can be accessed using standard file operations
2. Using S3 to large files - Download that during runtime rather than building as part of lambda package itself
3. Last but best, use lambda code as container images instead of zip files. Container images support code sizes upto 10 GB

Comment: But I think all of the 3 solutions will copy paste the files every time. Right? Let's suppose it takes 3 seconds to copy `500MB` model and another 2 seconds to load it. So it'll take at least 7 seconds for ANY of these approaches?

Comment: 1 & 2, you may face increased latencies but not with 3. Also, for ML models, please leverage AWS Sagemaker, you can have your model in S3, build a model and deploy the model with required capacity in sagemaker and you get a rest endpoint to consume in applications

Comment: EFS wouldn't involve any copying, though.

Comment: @omuthu but `Sagemaker` isn't as cost effective as `Lambda`, right? Main reason here is to cut the costs.

Comment: @gshpychka But `omuthu` says 1 and 2 can have increased time. If it doesn't copy, how can that be true?

Comment: Because EFS is slower than Lambda ephemeral storage. But not by very much, and it enables highly concurrent access - multiple Lambdas can load the model without copying.

Comment: As @gshpychka pointed out, EFS might slightly increase the latency compared to ephemeral storage but not much in the scale of seconds. And there is always tradeoff between cost vs performance, sagemaker was suggested as it was purpose built for deploying ML models and you will have the advantage to use ML features like labeling, training the models in a single environment/service, while lambda can suit your specific ML needs, it is a general purpose serverless compute environment/service